# Automatically updating input field with math using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

Ok I need some help, I have an online calculator where I have to get the lineal meter from two input fields. I need this to be automatic as they input the data. I have no idea how to do this.. any coding help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the html:

```
<input type="text" name="ancho" />
<input type="text" name="alto" />
<input type="text" name="material" />
```

I need it to output into this field:

```
<input type="text" name="ml" />
```

Here is the equation for the math side of it: 
(material/100) / ((alto/100) * (ancho/100))

Thank you in advance for this bit of help!

Comment: Please help!!! I need the material to be a select box and not an input!! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sigh** I don't see a lot of error checking on here in the solutions, so I thought I'd post *just one more*...

```
// locate all the input fields on the page
$(':input')
// bind to anything change related (down to keyboard changes so the element
// won't need to lose focus, or the user won't have to press enter)
.bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
    // retrieve the values of the inputs (we also call parseFloat to confirm
    // we are dealing with numeric values)
    var acho = parseFloat($(':input[name="acho"]').val(),10),
        alto = parseFloat($(':input[name="alto"]').val(),10),
        matl = parseFloat($(':input[name="material"]').val(),10);

    // default the end result to an empty string (you'll see
    // why with the following statement)
    var v = '';

    // confirm that all three values that go in to the equation are
    // all numbers before we try to perform any math functions. If
    // all goes well, "v" above will have the actual resulting value.
    // if any number is invalid, the "Result" field (ml) gets emptied
    if (!isNaN(acho) && !isNaN(alto) && !isNaN(matl)){

        // your math function
        v = (matl / 100) / ((alto / 100) * (acho / 100));
    }

    // replace the value of "ml" with our new calculated value
    $(':input[name="ml"]').val(v.toString());
});
```

...[With a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LhyuF/)

Comment: Did anyone else read `isNaN(acho)` as "is not a nacho"? Because I totally think that should be a built-in function.

Comment: @mblase75: Now that you mention it.... @Other Answers: May I ask what the point of answering a question with code and no comments is? SO isn't a "who can solve this problem first" site, it's a Q&A site. "Teach a man to fish" comes to mind. It's disappointing to see so many solutions without any kind of explanation backing them, which is arguably _more_ helpful to the OP (and future visitors) than the solution itself. `</rant>`

Comment: Hey I also have the same question for you.. how would I implement it if the material was a select box instead of an input?? I need to take the value of the select box.. thank you in advance!

Comment: @liveandream: `.val()` should work on a drop-down just the same as a select box. If not, you can use `$(':input[name="material"] :selected').val()` to get the selected option's value.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="material"],input[name="ancho"],input[name="alto"]').change(function(){
$('input[name="ml"]').val(($('input[name="material"]').val() / 100) / (($('input[name="alto"]').val() / 100) * ($('input[name="ancho"]').val() / 100)));
})
```

A **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Pmj4/)** here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('input[name="yourName"]').val()` to get value in each input and then apply your formula.

To set final result to result box use `$('input[name="yourName"]').val(results)`

something like:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
   //Get values
   var ancho= $('input[name="ancho"]').val();
   var alto= $('input[name="alto"]').val();
   var material= $('input[name="material"]').val();
   //Calculate results
    var results =  (material/100) / ((alto/100) * (ancho/100));

   //update output
   $('input[name="ml"]').val(results);
});
```

You can put about logic in `blur/change event` handler for your input

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ensangalufu/5fsDY/)

Answer (score 0):

this will update as you type in any of the fields. untested though.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var material = $('input[name="material"]').val(),
    alto = $('input[name="alto"]').val(),
    ancho = $('input[name="ancho"]').val(),
    result;

    if (material != "" && alto != "" && ancho != ""){
        result = (material/100) / ((alto/100) * (ancho/100));
        $('input[name="ml"]').val(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Evan I have a quick question for you.. if material was a select box instead of an input box, how would I code that into this? Thank you so much in advance!