# jQuery Math Operation on Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple invoicing page so I can invoice my client, however when I am going to perform multiplication to the quantity and price, the row total is not adding. Here's my jQuery so far.

```
$(":input").bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function(){
  var price = parseFloat($(this).closest('.tr').find('.price').val(),10),
  var qty = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.quantity').val(),10);
  var v = '';
  if(!isNaN(price) && !isNaN(qty)) {
    v = price * qty;
  }
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.rowtotal').val(v.toString());
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input name="item_name[]"class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="item_description[]"class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="item_price[]"class="form-control price"></td>
        <td><input name="item_quantity[]"class="form-control quantity"></td>
        <td><span class="rowtotal">0.00</span></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input name="item_name[]"class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="item_description[]"class="form-control"></td>
        <td><input name="item_price[]"class="form-control price"></td>
        <td><input name="item_quantity[]"class="form-control quantity"></td>
        <td><span class="rowtotal">0.00</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Now on my page, it shows no error while reviewing the console, but it does not perform the operation that I have created following this post "[Automatically updating input field with math using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900209/automatically-updating-input-field-with-math-using-jquery)"

Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo in this line:

```
var price = parseFloat($(this).closest('.tr').find('.price').val(),10),
                                        ^^ Shouldn't be a class selector
```

Should be:

```
var price = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val(),10),
```

Next line is fine. Additionally, you can replace all those events with:

```
$(":input").on("input", function() {
    // Triggers on any input event
});
```

You also have a few other issues:

1. There is no overload for `parseFloat` which takes two parameters
2. You are using `.val()` to set the text of the span. You need to use `.text()` instead
3. You should probably cache the `<tr>` selector. You don't need to go find it each time.

```
$(":input").on('input', function(){    
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var price = parseFloat($tr.find('.price').val()),
            qty = parseFloat($tr.find('.quantity').val());
        var v = '';
        if(!isNaN(price) && !isNaN(qty)) {
            v = price * qty;
        }
        $tr.find('.rowtotal').text(v.toString());
    });
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/19zq1mwm/)

Comment: Also, since `.rowtotal` is not an input element, `.val()` would not work. Using `.text()` should, and OP doesn't have to convert `v` to string :)

Comment: @Terry I'm getting there. Also there is no overload for parseFloat either - updating answer :)

Comment: Thank you guys, let me implement it.

Comment: Works well RGraham, does var $tr means I am caching the current tr?

Comment: @NimitzE. Exactly, means you find a reference to that `tr` once, then you can reuse it without having to search for it again

Comment: Thanks again. I am very knew to jquery, I only knew HTML and PHP

Comment: @rgraham,  what if I wanted to call that code you create in another jquery function, how can I do that?